# How to save datetime field value in config?

Tags: forms, 8, datetime

I have a custom module (`mymodule`) with a settings form. This form contains a datetime field (`mydate`) which I want to save in my modules config.

When I try to save this form I get an exception:

> Drupal\Core\Config\UnsupportedDataTypeConfigException: Invalid data type for config element mymodule.settings:mydate in Drupal\Core\Config\StorableConfigBase->validateValue() (line 160 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/Config/StorableConfigBase.php)

The form field:

```
$form['mydate'] = array(
  '#type' => 'datetime',
  '#title' => t('My date'),
  '#default_value' => $config->get('mydate')
)
```

The form submission handler where the error occures:

```
$config->set('mydate', $form_state->getValue('mydate));
```

I guess I have to set up my config schema to set up the "right type". Currently I have this one but it does not solve my issue:

```
mymodule.settings:
  type: config_object
  label: 'fancy module settings'
  mapping:
    mydate:
      type: datetime
      label: 'My date'
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong or what is missing?

PS: using Drupal 8.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no schema for data type called datetime.

Easiest solution is to store the date as the timestamp string.

Converting a drupal datetime into a timestamp:
The datetime form element holds an array value that contains three keys: `date`, `time`, `object`.
The `object` holds an instance of the `[\Drupal\Component\Datetime\DateTimePlus][1]` class. It has a _toString method which means it can be converted to string via normal casting (i.e. `(string) $value`).

Setting a default value on a datetime field:
Too do that you will need to create a new `[\Drupal\Component\Datetime\DateTimePlus][1]` object and set it as the value of `$element['#default_value']`

Comment: Could you please clear up how to convert a Drupal datetime into a timestamp and which config data type I have to use? This would complete your answer :)

Comment: Updated with sheets to your questions

Comment: According to the example commented inside the [datetime class](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Datetime%21Element%21Datetime.php/class/Datetime/8.3.x) I've used `'#default_value' => new DrupalDateTime($config->get('mydate'))`. _DrupalDateTime_ is an extension of DateTimePlus and works like charm in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Here's some actual code based on Eyal & Philipp's work in the other answer.

```
use Drupal\Core\Datetime\DrupalDateTime;
```

**Load:**

```
$form['mydate'] = [
    '#type'          => 'datetime',
    '#title'         => t('My date') ,
    '#default_value' => new DrupalDateTime( $config->get( 'mydate' ) ),
];
```

**Save:**

```
$config->set( 'mydate', $values['mydate']->__toString() )->save();
```

**config yaml:**

```
mydate: '2018-09-12 09:00:00 Europe/Berlin'
```

**Play with in console:**

```
$ drush php
Psy Shell v0.9.8 (PHP 7.1.22 — cli) by Justin Hileman
>>> use Drupal\Core\Datetime\DrupalDateTime;
>>> $time = new DrupalDateTime('2018-09-12 09:00:00 Europe/Berlin');
=> Drupal\Core\Datetime\DrupalDateTime {#4897}
>>> $time->getTimestamp();
=> 1536735600
```